Plotting Siesta Band Structure in Origin
I have obtained .bands file for my system using SIESTA. I furthur used the utility gnubands to convert it into .dat file. I want to make publication level plot. The plot of .dat file in both xmgrace and Origin is very strange.
I would like to prefer Origin. How to obtain a good quality plot of the SIESTA electronic bands with Origin?

Here is my input file:
SystemName ZnO221.cif
SystemLabel ZnO221.cif

NumberOfAtoms 8
NumberOfSpecies 2

%block Chemical_Species_label
1 30 Zn
2 8 O
%endblock Chemical_Species_label

LatticeConstant 1 Ang

%block LatticeVectors

 6.597500000       0.000000000       0.000000000

-3.298750000       5.713602602       0.000000000

 0.000000000       0.000000000      20.000000000

%endblock LatticeVectors



AtomicCoordinatesFormat Fractional
%block  AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
0.322294455       0.155389387       0.123471600    1
0.326648660       0.654671400       0.124133340    1
0.821475245       0.159609886       0.122727620    1
0.826083147       0.659083208       0.123468597    1
0.155348094       0.321979721       0.106444938    2
0.159752009       0.821741456       0.107382010    2
0.655073834       0.326331380       0.105458785    2
0.659312954       0.825816012       0.106426348    2
%endblock  AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies






# -- BAND-STRUCTURE-ANALYSIS --

BandLinesScale      pi/a

%block BandLines

1   0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  \Gamma

200 0.5000  0.0000  0.0000  M

200 0.3333  0.3333  0.0000  K

200 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  \Gamma

%endblock BandLines



Is that supposed to be a question? I don't see a question mark. I also think "is very strange" is not a useful problem description. Please be clearer about your actual question and the problem.

By strange I mean that bands in my plot has strange oscillating behaviour, egg shells like shapes. I have varied various input parameters but nothing works.  200 to 900 Ty meshccut off , 24 by 24 by kgrid, 200 k points along each symmetry lines are tested. I am using pseudopotentials and basis blocks provided by Simune Atomistic website. My system is 2 by 2 by 1 monolayer of ZnO

It could be good if you add an example here.

While this is a total guess (hard to say on so little evidence), did you run this calculation on a conventional rather than a primitive unit cell? If so, you might be experiencing issues with band folding. Either way, if we could see anything of your system and/or what the bands file it would be possible to be more confident about that!

I have added picture of bands in question.

This looks like a band folding issue (as @RobertLawrence already pointed) or a bad k-path selection.

I have added my basic input file
